# I have two entities and I want to perform a join query on them using jpa repository and retrive the new joined object

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hql

In my project, I have two tables with two entities.
They have a foreign key relationship between them.

I want to join them on and return a new object type. I generated entities from db scheme using persistence.

My first entity is UserEntity

```
package com.obss.Model.Jpa;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "conmigodb", catalog = "")
public class UserEntity {
private int userId;
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String password;
private boolean status;

public UserEntity(String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, boolean status) {
this.email=email;
this.firstName=firstName;
this.lastName=lastName;
this.password=password;
this.status=status;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "first_name")
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "last_name")
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "password")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "status")
public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UserEntity that = (UserEntity) o;

    if (userId != that.userId) return false;
    if (status != that.status) return false;
    if (email != null ? !email.equals(that.email) : that.email != null) return false;
    if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(that.firstName) : that.firstName != null) return false;
    if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(that.lastName) : that.lastName != null) return false;
    if (password != null ? !password.equals(that.password) : that.password != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = userId;
    result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (status ? 1 : 0);
    return result;
}
```

}

My second entity is UserDetailsEntity

```
package com.obss.Model.Jpa;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_details", schema = "conmigodb", catalog = "")
public class UserDetailsEntity {
private int userDetailsId;
private String address;
private String cellPhone;
private String graduatedSchool;
private String title;
private String experience;
private String description;
private UserEntity userByUserId;

@Id
@Column(name = "user_details_id")
public int getUserDetailsId() {
    return userDetailsId;
}

public void setUserDetailsId(int userDetailsId) {
    this.userDetailsId = userDetailsId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "address")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "cell_phone")
public String getCellPhone() {
    return cellPhone;
}

public void setCellPhone(String cellPhone) {
    this.cellPhone = cellPhone;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "graduated_school")
public String getGraduatedSchool() {
    return graduatedSchool;
}

public void setGraduatedSchool(String graduatedSchool) {
    this.graduatedSchool = graduatedSchool;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "title")
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "experience")
public String getExperience() {
    return experience;
}

public void setExperience(String experience) {
    this.experience = experience;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    UserDetailsEntity that = (UserDetailsEntity) o;

    if (userDetailsId != that.userDetailsId) return false;
    if (address != null ? !address.equals(that.address) : that.address != null) return false;
    if (cellPhone != null ? !cellPhone.equals(that.cellPhone) : that.cellPhone != null) return false;
    if (graduatedSchool != null ? !graduatedSchool.equals(that.graduatedSchool) : that.graduatedSchool != null)
        return false;
    if (title != null ? !title.equals(that.title) : that.title != null) return false;
    if (experience != null ? !experience.equals(that.experience) : that.experience != null) return false;
    if (description != null ? !description.equals(that.description) : that.description != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = userDetailsId;
    result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (cellPhone != null ? cellPhone.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (graduatedSchool != null ? graduatedSchool.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (title != null ? title.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (experience != null ? experience.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (description != null ? description.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
public UserEntity getUserByUserId() {
    return userByUserId;
}

public void setUserByUserId(UserEntity userByUserId) {
    this.userByUserId = userByUserId;
 }
```

}

I want to create a new object named UserProfile using mixed data between both this tables.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class named `UserProfile.class` and map all the columns that your query `DbQueries.FETCH_MIXED_DATA` is fetching like so

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class UserProfile {

    @Id 
    @Column(name="ROWNO")
    private String rowNumber;

    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;

    //Setters and getters

}
```

Try this

```
List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(DbQueries.FETCH_MIXED_DATA, UserProfile.class);
query.setParameter(":userId", GET_ID);
query.setParameter(":age", GET_AGE);

userProfiles = query.getResultList();
```

You can also return non-managed entity using Tranformers. Check out [this](http://in.relation.to/2006/03/17/hibernate-32-transformers-for-hql-and-sql/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your UserProfile has a constructor that takes in all the data it needs, try a  constructor query:

```
TypedQuery<UserProfile> query =
      em.createQuery("SELECT new UserProfile(user.userId, user.email, details.address) FROM UserDetailsEntity details join details.userByUserId user", UserProfile.class);
List<UserProfile> query.getResultList();
```